Problem with reseting password with firebase
my login page connects very well to firebase when I input user and password but when I click button reset password, it does not send reset link and it blacks out and returns to login page. I've recreated new activities and ran the connection to firebase but still no solution. Please see below my Forgot password Activity code and build gradle using java. I'm using Chipmunk version 2021 of android studio.
emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
Button resetPasswordButton = findViewById(R.id.resetPassword);
progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
resetPasswordButton.setOnClickListener(v - > {
    String email = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Please enter a registered email",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        emailEditText.setError("Email is Required");
        emailEditText.requestFocus();
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        emailEditText.setError("Valid email is Required");
        emailEditText.requestFocus();
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        resetPassword();
    }
});
}
private void resetPassword() {
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(Email).addOnCompleteListener(task - > {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Please check inbox for reset password 
                    link!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    new Intent(ForgetPassword.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    //Clear stack to prevent user coming back to ForgotPassword
                    startActivity(null); finish();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Something went wrong!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            });
    }
}


build.gradle
buildscript{
    dependencies{
        classpath"com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
    }
    //Top-levelbuildfilewhereyoucanaddconfiguration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    plugins{
       id'com.android.application'version'7.2.2'apply false
       id'com.android.library'version'7.2.2'apply false
    }allprojects{
    repositories{
        
    }
    }taskclean(type: Delete){
        deleterootProject.buildDir
    }


The variable "Email" you are passing in function;
 mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(Email)

is not what you are getting in the
String email = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();

make sure you are using correct variable.
For Activity:
replace this:
new Intent(ForgetPassword.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    //Clear stack to prevent user coming back to ForgotPassword
                    startActivity(null); finish();

With this:
Intent intent = new Intent(ForgetPassword.this, LoginActivity.class);
            //this how you clear stack to prevent user coming back to ForgotPassword
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

Edited for more clearity:
In your

resetPassword()
make it to accept string email as parameter already done that in code see below. and pass that email to the firebase function. Now when you call the resetPassword() pass an email string to it. like done in below code

emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
Button resetPasswordButton = findViewById(R.id.resetPassword);
progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
resetPasswordButton.setOnClickListener(v - > {
    String email = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Please enter a registered email",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        emailEditText.setError("Email is Required");
        emailEditText.requestFocus();
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        emailEditText.setError("Valid email is Required");
        emailEditText.requestFocus();
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        resetPassword(email);
    }
});
}
private void resetPassword(String email) {
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(task - > {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Please check inbox for reset password 
                    link!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    new Intent(ForgetPassword.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    //Clear stack to prevent user coming back to ForgotPassword
                    startActivity(null); finish();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Something went wrong!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            });
    }
}


Thanks for replying Samad. I just replaced your intent activity with mine and tried resetting password, it does not send reset link and it blacks out and returns to login page.

If you have set the variable in correct way, It should work now. Check your firebase configurations to send emails.

And before passing the variable check whether it contains the email.
mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(Email) in this code you have to pass the correct variable that contains the email.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#java
go through this as well.

check this example here
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-password-of-user-in-android-using-firebase/

i have updated the answer. it should work now.
